# Firebird query taking too long when using IN clause with Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, firebird

For a report I had to write a recursive Stored Procedure `GET_RECIPE_STEPS_ID(recipe_id)`. It returns ids of steps which are of type recipe. I.E.

```
SELECT GET_RECIPE_STEPS_ID.ID FROM GET_RECIPE_STEPS_ID(3189)

It Returns
3189
3190
3191
3192
```

When I run it on it's own It's quick (like 0.031sec execution time). But if it is to be used with IN clause in a query it takes ages. Like the following query took almost 12 minutes.

```
SELECT rs.RECIPEID
FROM RECIPESTEPS rs
WHERE rs.RECIPEID IN (select GET_RECIPE_STEPS_ID.ID from GET_RECIPE_STEPS_ID(3189))
```

Which is equivalent to the following query, and almost as quick as the stored procedure itself (0.038sec)

```
Select rs.RECIPEID
FROM RECIPESTEPS rs
WHERE rs.RECIPEID IN (3189, 3190, 3191, 3192)
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE GET_RECIPE_STEPS_ID 
 (recipe_id integer) 
RETURNS 
 (id integer)
AS 
declare variable coType integer;
BEGIN
  /* Recursive Procedure 
   * For Passed Recipe 'Recipe_id', it Returns the step's which are of type Recipe again.
   * 
   * If any step is of type Recipe(i.e COTYPE = 1)
   * Then it calls itself again for that step(Recipe) 
   */
    id =: recipe_id;
    SUSPEND;

    FOR SELECT rs.COMMODITYID, c.COTYPE
        FROM RECIPESTEPS rs 
        LEFT JOIN COMMODITIES c ON c.COMMODITYID = rs.COMMODITYID
        WHERE rs.RECIPEID  =: recipe_id INTO :id, :coType
    Do
    BEGIN
        IF(coType = 1)
        THEN 
            FOR SELECT r.RECIPEID FROM RECIPES r WHERE r.LATEST = 1 AND r.COMMODITYID =:id into :id
            DO
            BEGIN
                FOR SELECT GET_RECIPE_STEPS_ID.ID
                    FROM GET_RECIPE_STEPS_ID(:id) INTO :id
                DO
                BEGIN
                    SUSPEND;
                END
            END     
    END 
END^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is two-fold:

1. `IN` does not have very good performance to begin with and
2. In this situation the stored procedure gets executed for each row and not once like you would expect; I guess the Firebird optimizer doesn't infer that this stored procedure invocation is not correlated with the query.

It will probably perform better if you transform your query to use an `INNER JOIN` instead of `IN`:

```sql
select rs.RECIPEID
from GET_RECIPE_STEPS_ID(3189) grs
inner join RECIPESTEPS rs
  on rs.RECIPEID = grs.ID
```

I assume that your real query might be more complex, because otherwise just `select ID from GET_RECIPE_STEPS_ID(3189)` would suffice.

The above query will behave slightly different than `IN`, for example if an `ID` occurs multiple times in the stored procedure output, it will also produce multiple rows now. You may need to adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Mark for suggestion, avoiding IN clause significantly reduces the execution time. And even more if I use the stored procedure in the beginning of my actual query.

Comment: @AlphaTry Yes, order can be very important, because the behavior for stored procedures on the right hand side of a join can also resulted in repeated executions IIRC.

Comment: AFAIR it is better to use left/right join when using SP, to avoid extra call of SP on <non-existent> all-null table row